# How to check if a branch contains the same thing as the master branch

Tags: git

Are there any ways in which I can check to see if this particular branch contains the same thing as the master branch?

I know of a tedious and manual way, which is checking and comparing the branches within the repo, it may work if it does not contains a lot of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're in the branch you want to check:

```
git diff HEAD master
```

Comment: And, when you're not in the branch you want to check: `git diff <branch> master`...

Answer (score 0):

For a programmatic way that returns an exit status based on whether there is a diff or not, we can use [`diff-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index):

```sh
git diff-index --quiet master
```

If there is no diff between the current branch and `master`, this'll return a successful exit status, and if there is a diff, it'll return a non-zero exit status.

To use that in a script, for example, to only do something if there is a diff:

```sh
if ! git diff-index --quiet master; then
    echo "There is a diff"
    # Do something
fi
```